# Get React.js component by name or something

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

i'm new to React and wondering if there is some way to directly operate with some component using it's name, ID, key, anything.

For example i'm creating simple game and there are lots of 'cells'.
Cell have `state.cellState` of `enabled`, `disabled` or `active`.

Once cell is clicked it becomes `active` and after `Enter` is pressed - `disabled`.

That is the point - is it possible to get active Cell and operate with it?

I'm using Electron, `Enter` and others shortcuts already work.

EDIT - Here is some code

```
class Main extends React.Component {
render() {
    let rows = [];

    categories.forEach(function (category, i) {
        rows.push(<Row categoryName={category} rowNo={i + 1} key={category}/>);
    });

    return (
        <div className="clearfix" id="main">
            {rows}
        </div>
    );
}

let Row = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    let notes = [],
        categoryId = this.props.rowNo;

    bonuses.forEach(function (bonus, i) {
        let id = 'cell_' + categoryId.toString() + (i + 1).toString();
        notes.push(<NoteCell bonus={bonus} id={id} key={id}/>);
    });

    return (
        <div className="row clearfix">
            <CategoryCell categoryName={this.props.categoryName}/>
            {notes}
        </div>
    )
}
});

class CategoryCell extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="cell category">
            <h2>
                {this.props.categoryName}
            </h2>
        </div>
    )
}
}

let NoteCell = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return {active: true}
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="cell tune" id={this.props.id} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <div className="tune-container">
                <img src="./static/note.png" className="note"/>
            </div>
            <h3 className="value">{this.props.bonus}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
});
```

So components initialy have `enabled` state and are created dinamically.
How can i get current active cell and operate with it?
Sorry for formating and ES2015 mixin.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when and where you want to do that operation.

1. If you want to do it **before** the rendering inside the `Cell` component , you can simply check whether the currentState is active before updating the state and do your processing.
2. If you want to do it **after** the rendering inside the `Cell` component , you can pass your function as a callback to setState method which you call after updating the `Cell` state.
3. If you want to make changes from the parent view, you need to lift the `Cell` state to the parent view and then apply a filter to get the 'active' cell states. Once you have the states corresponding to `active` cells, you can change those states to what you want which will re-render the `Cell` instances (You will need to implement `componentsWillReceiveProps()` in the `Cell` component to reflect these changes)

This case most probably falls in the 3rd case. You can pull out the state to the `Row` class as follows. In case you want to do those actions from the `Main` component, you will need to lift up the state to the `Main` component. If you can tell what exactly you want to do with active items, I can explain further

```
    class Main extends React.Component {
        render() {
            let rows = [];

            categories.forEach(function (category, i) {
                rows.push(<Row categoryName={category} rowNo={i + 1} key={category} />)
            });

            return (
                <div className="clearfix" id="main">
                    {rows}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    class Row extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            this.state = {
                categoryId: props.rowNo,
                bonuses: props.bonuses,
            }
            props.bonuses.forEach((bonus, i) => this.state[i] = true)
        }

        handleActiveItems() {
            var activeItems = this.bonuses.filter(x => x.status);
            // Process active Items
        }

        handleClick(i) {
            return (e) => {
                var updatedState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
                updatedState[i] = e.target.value; // Use state setting logic here
                this.setState(updatedState);
            }
        }

        render() {
            let notes = [];
            let categoryId = this.props.rowNo;

            bonuses.forEach(function (bonus, i) {
                let id = 'cell_' + categoryId.toString() + (i + 1).toString();
                notes.push(<NoteCell bonus={bonus} id={id} key={id} status={this.state.status} handleClick={this.handleClick(i).bind(this)} />);
            });

            return (
                <div className="row clearfix">
                    <CategoryCell categoryName={this.props.categoryName} />
                    {notes}
                    <button onClick={this.handleActiveItems}>Click me to change all active buttons in this row</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    class CategoryCell extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                < div className="cell category" >
                    <h2>
                        {this.props.categoryName}
                    </h2>
                </div >
            )
        }
    }

    class NoteCell extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            this.state = {
                id: props.id,
                status: props.status
            }
            this.handleClick = props.handleClick;
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            this.setState(nextProps)
        }

        render() {
            // Check status and render different types of NoteCell
            return (
                <div className="cell tune" id={this.props.id} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <div className="tune-container">
                        <img src="./static/note.png" className="note" />
                    </div>
                    <h3 className="value">{this.props.bonus}</h3>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i don't quite understand. Please look at code i've add above.

Comment: It's some kind of 'guess the tune' game. Player choose cell, listen for midi-song and tries to understand what song is it. As soon he understands he should press `spacebar` and [what is most important] cell becomes disabled. That's the point i cannot understand! How can i change some `NoteCell` state by shortcut? Smth like `NoteCell[23].setState(.....)`

Comment: I'm assuming only 1 cell can be listened to at one time. So whenever you set the state to active, start playing music. Once, the user hits spacebar you need to change the state to disabled in the "handleActiveItem". For this, maintain the status in the Main Component and add a global event listener which invokes a function when space bar is pressed. That function will set the state to disabled and will render the updated UI. Detecting global spacebar is tricky. Read about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/285)